# OpenWRT, ipv6 is not connected, I can't ping global ipv6 addresses, ipv4 is working fine though

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, openwrt

I need help with my setup which is :

```
ISP router LAN port => OpenWRT router WAN port.

OpenWRT router LAN ports and WIFI => my home devices
```

I am running default OpenWRT out of the box configuration.
The WAN interface of OpenWRT router gets assigned global ipv6 address by the ISP router.
My devices gets assigned local ipv6 addresses by the OpenWRT router.

The problem is ipv6 is not working in the LAN device (Windows PC).
It means I can't ping an ipv6 global address like google DNS (2001:4860:4860::8888) from my LAN device.

IPv6 connectivity status in Windows PC:

[image]

But if I connect my Windows PC directly to ISP router's LAN port then
I can ping the global ipv6 address.

My OpenWRT router is TP-Link MR3420 v5

Does OpenWRT not support ipv6 out of the box?
Do I need to change some configuration?

Comment: Perhaps your OpenWRT settings for DHCP are different for IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: @harrymc Then be a dear and tell me the correct settings?

Comment: Please include screenshots of the router settings for both IPv4 and IPv6 in your post, my dear.

Comment: @harrymc thats sounds like a lot of screenshots

Comment: @harrymc https://postimg.cc/pyyz6Zsq

Comment: https://postimg.cc/rK6jGxQz

Comment: https://postimg.cc/pmMjytR6

Comment: The `DHCPv6-Service` is in `server mode`, which I take to mean that it create an IPv6 network of its own. Can this be turned off?

Comment: @harrymc I'll try. Actually I found this link https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/ipv6/configuration#ipv6_relay , I am gonna disable the server mode and try the relay mode and check whether the home devices gets assigned the global addresses instead of local addresses

Comment: @harrymc relay method worked. I changed server mode to relay mode and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I changed DHCPv6 to relay mode as mentioned here

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/ipv6/configuration#ipv6_relay

And it worked. The home devices are now getting ipv6 addresses directly from ISP router. This is enough for my needs.

[ipv6 connected status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QDgb.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).